# Open javascript popup after jquery response

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I have this simple javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.check', function(){
               $.post('/index.php',
               {
                   article: '1'
               },

               function(data, textStatus)
               {
                window.open('https://google.com');
               });
     });
});
</script> 

<button class=".check">Check</buttton>
```

Although the click is user initiated but the popup is getting blocked by browsers. How to avoid this?

Comment: window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");

Comment: Are you popping up a another web page all the time?

Comment: @Dean.DePue what do you mean by all the time? I open it as a response to the click on the button

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to unblock it through code.

Most browsers feel popups are very interrupting and that's the reason they block it.

You can only find out if the popup is being blocked and promptly notify the user to unblock it.

```
var wind =  window.open('https://google.com');
if(!wind || wind.closed || typeof wind.closed=='undefined') 
{ 
     //POPUP BLOCKED
alert("please enable popups");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pop-up should be triggered **directly** by user interaction. But instead it's in an AJAX callback.

So, to prevent the block you should open the pop-up within the `click` handler. Then make the post..

**EDIT:** A tricky method would be to open the popup directly, then make the request and finally redirect the popup to the result URL:

```
$(document).on('click', '.check', function(){
    var popup = window.open('/loading.html', 'popup');
    $.post('/index.php', { article: '1' },
        function (data, textStatus) {
            popup.location.href = 'http://new-url';
        });
 });
```

Comment: It can't be like this as the URL opened depends on the query response. this is just a simplified example

Comment: I understand but this is how browsers behave, to prevent annoying popups. In most browsers, this is the only way to open a popup without being blocked. You might get around this by hiding the popup until the AJAX callback is completed. But that's a bit tricky too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick:

```
function(data, textStatus)
{
    var anchor = $( '<a/>', {href:'https://google.com',target:'_blank'} ).text( 'TEST' );
    $('body').append( anchor );
    $('body').find( 'a' ).last()[0].click();
    anchor.remove();
};
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/5xhyL/)